# Decision Tree Find Recursive Node C++

Tags: c++, recursion, decision-tree

The mission is to find in decision tree node with value.
return the node if exists and return null if does not exists.

My struct is:

```
class ValidAnswer
{
public:
    string ans;
    DecisionTreeNode* son;
....
};

class DecisionTreeNode
{
public:
    string value;
    bool isLeaf;
    list<ValidAnswer*> answersList;

    DecisionTreeNode* findNode(string _value);
....


};
```

I wrote the recursive function for finding but it does not work.
I find way to make this function to work.

**This is my function:**

```
DecisionTreeNode* DecisionTreeNode::findNode(string _value){
    if (value == _value){
        return this;
    }
    if (answersList.size() > 0){
        list<ValidAnswer*>::iterator it;
        for (it = answersList.begin(); it != answersList.end(); ++it){
            if ((*it)->son != nullptr){
                return  ((*it)->son)->findNode(_value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Care to add an example of a tree you are trying to search as well as to tell us _how_ it doesn't work, i.e. what do you expect to happen vs. what actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((*it)->son != nullptr){
            return  ((*it)->son)->findNode(_value);
```

Something to note here is that once you find a valid `son`, you delegate the responsibility to get an answer to it. You do not see a possibility of an answer with other `son's`.

```
if ((*it)->son != nullptr)
{
   auto GotIt = ((*it)->son)->findNode(_value);
   if(GotIt)
        return GotIt;
} //If we didn't get an answer from this it, we will check for next son.
```